# State/Province display for a contact shows a number instead of the name for Vietnam contacts

Tags: contacts, addresses

Most of my contacts have Vietnamese addresses. When I enter the name (organization or individual), I see the correct name for the Vietnamese provinces in the list and choose one. When I view the contact details, the name of the province displays as a number (the id, I presume) instead of the name.

I have reported this several times on the old forum but never got a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I don't think it is the ID, rather it is the 'abbreviation' which in the case of Viet Nam have all been entered in to table civicrm_state_province as numbers.

```
SELECT * from `civicrm_state_province`
WHERE country_id = 1233
```

whereas eg US ones are of type WV (West Virginia) etc

I don't know how bad it would be to suggest you copy the 'name' field and paste in to the 'abbreviation' field as a really bad hack.

I know I also raised this on the [forum](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,34019.0.html) in the past with the hope of a solution so that there was a setting you could nominate to use either the Abbreviation or the Name on the Contacts Summary screen

Comment: Hi Peter...sorry it took so long to come back to this but ran into the same problem again today. I wonder where these numbers they are using for abbreviations came from. I don't know if VN has official abbreviations but I am sure they are not numbers. It would be nice if someone from civicrm.org would get involved in this after several years of bringing it up.

Comment: I just looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:VN and see what the source of the numbers is. It is the code column in the ISO 3166-2 table but without the preceding "VN".  I also noticed that in the CiviCRM table, the names have been anglicized so that a province like Đắk Lắk is spelled Dac Lac in the CiviCRM table.

Comment: Correct - they are the ISO number

Comment: This is still an issue. I don't mind fixing the table but I'm afraid it would be lost in an update.

Comment: What I'd like to be able to do is use a token for the fully spelled out province name instead of fiddlling with the table. Right now, the only token available is the abbreviation, which is just a number. Same for Cambodia.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here in Ireland.
[Export full state name - not abbreviation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37951)
The solution is needed for most countries apart from USA and Canada. The exports need to include civicrm_state_province name as well as civicrm_state_province abbreviation.

Comment: is this an Answer or a Comment?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/11807)

Comment: Including civicrm_state_province name as well as civicrm_state_province abbreviation in the exports would answer the problem.